# Accessing data from a nested class elegantly

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11

I have the following class:

```
class BigNum
{
public:
    BigNum(string StrNumber) : Number(std::move(StrNumber)) {}
    BigNum(const char *StrNumber) : Number(string(StrNumber)) {}
    ~BigNum() = default;

    struct
    {
        string HEX() { return Number + " - HEX"; }
        string DEC() { return Number + " - DEC"; }
        string BIN() { return Number + " - BIN"; }
    }ToString;

private:
    string Number;
};
```

And in the end I wand to elegantly access functions from that structure in the following way:

```
BigNum a = "1234";
cout << "a = " << a.ToString.DEC() << endl;
cout << "b = " << a.ToString.HEX() << endl;
```

The problem here is that I cannot access variable `Number` from my structure.

I know that something like this would solve my problem:

```
struct
{
    string HEX(BigNum &parent) { return parent.Number + " - HEX"; }
...
}ToString;
```

The problem with this solution is that it is not comfortable to always pass a pointer to my instance.

What would be a solution in this case to have data in nested class and in the same time to keep calls as simple as `a.ToString.DEC()`?

Comment: What's the purpose of having a proxy object (`ToString`)  instead of just implementing the three member functions in `BigNum` directly?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am thinking that in the future it may be easier to reuse that. And it's easier to disable that option by only removing the instance to that structure.

Comment: If you don't see any use for it right now, you could postpone implementing it like this untill the need for that proxy object arises. Chances are that it never will.

Comment: It looks a bit like the [named parameter](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html) idiom. Not necessarily a bad idea.

Comment: @Erlkoenig I don't see the similarity. Returning `*this` from methods, which allows all sorts of good things, like chaining, has little in common with this proxy object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some way you have to give `ToString` a reference or a pointer to the `BigNum` object so you can access `Number`. How about something like this:

```
class BigNum
{
public:
    BigNum(string StrNumber) : Number(std::move(StrNumber)) {}
    BigNum(const char* StrNumber) : Number(string(StrNumber)) {}
    ~BigNum() = default;

    // you can make the struct private so the type is not visible externally
    struct ToStringType
    {
    private:
        const BigNum& ref;

    public:
        ToStringType(const BigNum& r) : ref(r) {}

        string HEX() { return ref.Number + " - HEX"; }
        string DEC() { return ref.Number + " - DEC"; }
        string BIN() { return ref.Number + " - BIN"; }
    };

    ToStringType ToString{ *this };

private:
    string Number;
};
```

Irrelevant, but I would recommend to simply have separate `ToStringHex`, `ToStringDec` and `ToStringBin` functions. Saves on not storing a reference, plus the API is easier this way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any rationale in the ToString struct.

Just leave the methods in BIGNUM and you are done.

However, for this specific application (changing the rendering style of your given objet in an `ostream`) I would let your object to be printed with the typical `operator<<` overaloading, and then modify the rendering style using io-manipulators, so that you will be able to:

```
cout << "a (DEC) = " << BigNum::DEC << a << endl;
cout << "a (HEX) = " << BigNum::HEX << a << endl;
```

A full fledged example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class BigNum
{
public:
    BigNum(string StrNumber) : Number(std::move(StrNumber)) {}
    BigNum(const char *StrNumber) : Number(string(StrNumber)) {}
    ~BigNum() = default;

    static std::ios_base& DEC(std::ios_base& os) {
        os.iword(rendering_style_xalloc) = 0;
        return os;
    }

    static std::ios_base& HEX(std::ios_base& os) {
        os.iword(rendering_style_xalloc) = 1;
        return os;
    }

    static std::ios_base& BIN(std::ios_base& os) {
        os.iword(rendering_style_xalloc) = 2;
        return os;
    }
private:
    static int rendering_style_xalloc;
    string Number;

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &ostr, const BigNum &bignum);
};

int BigNum::rendering_style_xalloc = std::ios_base::xalloc();

ostream &operator << (ostream &os, const BigNum &bignum) {
    switch (os.iword(BigNum::rendering_style_xalloc)) {
        case 0:
            os << bignum.Number << " - DEC";
            break;
        case 1:
            os << bignum.Number << " - HEX";
            break;
        case 2:
            os << bignum.Number << " - BIN";
            break;
        default:
            os << bignum.Number << " - UNK";
            break;
    }
    return os;
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    BigNum a = "1234";
    cout << BigNum::DEC << "a (DEC) = " << a << endl;
    cout << BigNum::HEX << "a (HEX) = " << a << endl;   
}
```

References:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iword